# MySQL GROUP BY field with highest COUNT (based on JOIN)

Tags: mysql, sql, innodb

```
SELECT COUNT(dev_link.id) c, pattern.direction, pattern.section, (
    SELECT to_stop AS `stop`
    FROM dev_link d
    WHERE d.section = section
    ORDER BY d.sequence DESC
    LIMIT 1
) code
FROM pattern
INNER JOIN dev_link ON dev_link.section = pattern.section
WHERE pattern.service = "YSEO252"
GROUP BY pattern.code
ORDER BY c DESC
```

[image]

Above is a query and its results. Currently this is selecting too much  data, I need to narrow it down to the following:

1 row with direction `outbound` and another row with direction `inbound`. If it was just that I could easily `GROUP BY` the direction. However, I need to select an `inbound` and an `outbound` row with the highest `c` value. So based on the results above the 1st row and the third row would be selected.

How can I change my query so that it returns these rows?

Comment: ~~Is there a reason you can't use `HAVING COUNT(dev_link.id) = MAX(COUNT(dev_link.id)) OVER(PARTITION BY direction)`?~~ Nevermind, windowing functions aren't allowed in a HAVING Clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
( SELECT ... WHERE ... AND pattern.direction='inbound' ... LIMIT 1)
UNION ALL
( SELECT ... WHERE ... AND pattern.direction='outbound' ... LIMIT 1 );
```

Otherwise, the each SELECT is like the original one.

Comment: Great, simple solution. Thanks Rick!

Answer (score 1):

I would use variables to simulate row_number()

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT * , 
        @rn := if(@prevDirection = direction, @rn + 1, 1) as rn,
        @prevDirection := direction,
    FROM (
        SELECT COUNT(dev_link.id) c, pattern.direction, pattern.section, (
            SELECT to_stop AS `stop`
            FROM dev_link d
            WHERE d.section = section
            ORDER BY d.sequence DESC
            LIMIT 1
        ) code
        FROM pattern
        INNER JOIN dev_link ON dev_link.section = pattern.section
        WHERE pattern.service = "YSEO252"
        GROUP BY pattern.code
    ) t1 ORDER BY direction, c DESC
) t1 WHERE rn = 1
```

Comment: This query returns 0 rows

Comment: @jskidd3 what does the inner query return `SELECT *, @rn := if ...` ?

Comment: @jskidd3 I forgot to name the rn column, updated answer try again

Comment: Actually, hold on I have found a problem. Whenever the query is executed for the first time it returns all the rows. Do you know why this is? I will re-award best answer when this has been solved.

Comment: @jskidd3 not sure try adding `t1 cross join (select @rn := null, @prevDirection := null) t2 ORDER BY direction, c DESC ...`

Comment: Could you put that code into your answer? I'm not sure how to work that into the query

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use MAX function additionally with group by clause like:

```
SELECT MAX(c)
FROM mytable
GROUP BY direction
```

Comment: Adding `MAX()` around the `COUNT()` function creates error: `Invalid use of group function`

Answer (score -2):

You have to use the `having` clause.

```
SELECT COUNT(dev_link.id) c, pattern.direction, pattern.section, (
    SELECT to_stop AS `stop`
    FROM dev_link d
    WHERE d.section = section
    ORDER BY d.sequence DESC
    LIMIT 1
) code
FROM pattern
INNER JOIN dev_link ON dev_link.section = pattern.section
WHERE pattern.service = "YSEO252"
GROUP BY pattern.code
HAVING COUNT(dev_link.id) = MAX(COUNT(dev_link.id))
ORDER BY c DESC
```

Comment: He needs to have it by direction, and you can't use windowing functions in a having clause. I had the same mistake.